# Can two people play Sea of Thieves simultaneously on PC and Xbox with only one copy of the game?

Tags: pc, xbox-one, sea-of-thieves

I own a copy of Sea of Thieves on PC and I am thinking of buying a Xbox One S. I would like to know if its possible to play the game at the same time on both devices without buying another copy?

Sea of Thieves is a 'Xbox Play Anywhere' title so I will be able to download and install the game on the Xbox console without buying it again and it will transfer my character profile and faction progress.

What is not clear on the play anywhere [FAQ page](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/xbox-play-anywhere) is whether the game can be played simultaneously on Xbox and PC so that the second player can log in with there own Xbox account (not the same account that owns the game) and be able to join my crew online for some casual swashbuckling.

Comment: Haven't tried this, but I think you can if the other player is logged in using their GamerTag on your Xbox (which you have set to your Home Xbox). I've heard of that working with using 1 copy of the game to play on 2 Xboxes, so it seems like it could work with Xbox & PC too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using a single copy of the game, you cannot log into Sea of Thieves simultaneously from the same account on both Xbox and PC.** From [the news post about Xbox Play Anywhere on xbox.com](https://news.xbox.com/en-us/2016/09/15/everything-you-need-to-know-about-xbox-play-anywhere/):

> **Can I be signed into the same game on Xbox One and my Windows 10 PC?**
>
> At any single point in time, you may only sign into the game on one Xbox One console or one Windows 10 PC. You cannot be signed into the same game on both platforms at the same time.

If you try, you'll receive a message asking if you want to sign out of the other location. On PC:

[image: Error when logging into an Xbox Play Anywhere title on both Xbox and PC from the same account]

**Using a single copy of the game, you can log into Sea of Thieves simultaneously on both Xbox and PC as long as you use different Xbox accounts.**

I verified this with my Xbox Gold account and my spouse's Xbox Silver account. As long as I made sure that the account used on the PC copy was not signed in on the Xbox, we could log in at the same time.

I realize this is not *verifiable* proof, but both characters in the below screenshot are logged in using a single copy of the game:

[image: Two different accounts logged into a single copy of Sea of Thieves, Xbox Play Anywhere edition]

I have yet to find any official word on whether this behavior is intended.

Comment: Having read the Reddit thread and news post a number of times I am not 100% sure that the references back up your answer. The news post specifically says that the same account cannot be signed in to the same game at the same time but what if the Xbox is using a second account with the account that owns the game being the home console?  Also the first Reddit comment seems to be saying that it is possible using two different accounts. The second Reddit comment seems to be saying that it is not possible with family account link to the account that owns the game.

Comment: @Colin Good callout. I missed this aspect of your original question. I updated my answer after experimenting with this myself.

Comment: Yep - the digital download version can be shared via XBox game sharing and Windows App Sharing between multiple accounts on different devices - To be clear though: I have set up a Microsoft Family, with individual accounts for all users, so that means that my son and I can both play my single instance of the game, with one of us on the XBox and the other on the PC.

Answer (score -3):

It's multiplayer online, not localy. So, no two people can not play on the same console or with only one disc even if the other person owns the same console they have to have the game